# How can I convert MM::SS string into HMS format

Tags: r, time, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(tm = c("30:15", "29:18", "30:38")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(title = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), tm = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"))
```

It looks like this (column format is character):

```
 tm   
  <chr>
1 30:15
2 29:18
3 30:38
```

What I want to do is to convert into `hms::as_hms` format from **[hms](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hms/versions/0.4.2/topics/hms)** package.

```
# this is a dput from text parsing package
hms_df <- structure(list(tm = structure(c(108900, 105480, 110280), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

like this:

```
 tm    
  <time>
1 30:15 
2 29:18 
3 30:38
```

Why this code doesn't work

```
df %>% 
 mutate(tm = hms::as_hms(tm))
```

it gives:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `ntm`.
ℹ `ntm = hms::as_hms(tm)`.
x Lossy cast from <character> to <hms> at position(s) 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: @ViníciusFélix Not quite. That's why I put up a new one again. I specifically need hms::as_hms format.

Comment: Please specify your end goal in your main post. Do you just want to change `tm` to `hms::as_hms` format? Is that it?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes exactly! Just to change to hms::as_hms format.

Comment: @ViníciusFélix `hms_df` is the end format I want my `df` to become. I stated quite clearly in my OP.

Comment: Do you have to provide the hours as well, like `as_hms(paste0("00:", df$tm))` ? The help file `?as_hms` seem to suggest that's the case - "*For hms, all arguments must have the same length or be NULL. Odd combinations (e.g., passing only seconds and hours but not minutes) are rejected.*"

Comment: @thelatemail It is only strictly in `minute:second` format not need `hours`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `hms` requires hours, minutes and seconds. In the data you only have minutes and seconds. You may append dummy `'00'` value as hours.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(tm = hms::as_hms(sprintf('00:%s', tm))) 
df

#   tm    
#  <time>
#1 30'15"
#2 29'18"
#3 30'38"

df$tm
#00:30:15
#00:29:18
#00:30:38
```

Answer (score 3):

`as.PosIXct` then `as_hms` works

```
hms::as_hms(as.POSIXct(df$tm, format = "%M:%S"))

00:30:15
00:29:18
00:30:38
```